# What does `cryptsetup resize` do if LUKS doesn't store partition size?

Tags: luks, dm-crypt, cryptsetup, volume, device-mapper

The `LUKS` / `dm-crypt` / `cryptsetup` [FAQ page](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) says:

> 2.15 Can I resize a dm-crypt or LUKS partition?
>
> Yes, you can, as neither dm-crypt nor LUKS stores partition size.

I'm befuzzled:

1. What is "resized" if no size information is stored?
2. How does a "resize" get remembered across open / closes of a encrypted volume?

Comment: I don't think cryptsetup or LUKS affect the partition table. On a LUKS encrypted container, the disk partitioning  is still performed by a tool like `parted` and stored in the partition table. I think the LUKS system is applied as a file format, i.e. you would partition the disk, then after that operation - which defines the partition size, then you would apply the LUKS file format, instead of say, ext4. So in short "resizing" just would not be applicable to LUKS. i.e. you wouldn't say *Can I resize ext4?*

Comment: `man cryptsetup` : "resize <name>
              Resizes an active mapping <name>.
              If  --size (in sectors) is not specified, the size of the underlying block device is used. Note that this does not change  the  device  geometry,  it  just  changes  how  many sectors of the device are represented in the mapped device."

Comment: @the_velour_fog `resize2fs` resizes an ext2/3/4 BLOB as these have a concept of the a last block, see `tune2fs -l`.

Comment: @cylgalad So how does one remember that "resize" across mounts? I couldn't see a `mount` option for this.

Comment: I got my eyes checked: the `open` action has a `--size` argument.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's about *online* resize.

For example if you use LVM, create a LV of 1G size, and put LUKS on that, it's like this:

```
# lvcreate -L1G -n test VG
# cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/mapper/VG-test
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/VG-test lukstest
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mapper/VG-test
1073741824
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mapper/lukstest
1071644672
```

So the LUKS device is about the same size as the VG-test device (1G minus 2MiB used by the LUKS header).

Now what happens when you make the LV larger?

```
# lvresize -L+1G /dev/mapper/VG-test
  Size of logical volume VG/test changed from 1.00 GiB (16 extents) to 2.00 GiB (32 extents).
  Logical volume test successfully resized.
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mapper/VG-test
2147483648
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mapper/lukstest
1071644672
```

The LV is 2G large now, but the LUKS device is still stuck at 1G, as that was the size it was originally opened with.

Once you `luksClose` and `luksOpen`, it would also be 2G — because LUKS does not store a size, it defaults to the device size at the time you open it. So close and open (or simply rebooting) would update the crypt mapping to the new device size. However, since you can only close a container after umounting/stopping everything inside of it, this is basically an *offline resize*.

But maybe you have a mounted filesystem on the LUKS, it's in use, and you don't want to umount it for the resize, and that's where `cryptsetup resize` comes in as an *online* resize operation.

```
# cryptsetup resize /dev/mapper/lukstest
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mapper/lukstest
2145386496
```

`cryptsetup resize` updates the active crypt mapping to the new device size, no umount required, and then you can follow it up with `resize2fs` or whatever to also grow the mounted filesystem itself online.

If you don't mind rebooting or remounting, you'll never need `cryptsetup resize` as it happens automatically offline. But if you want to do it *online*, that's the only way.

---

When shrinking (`cryptsetup resize --size x`), the resize is temporary. LUKS does not store device size, so next time you luksOpen, it will simply use the device size again. So shrinking sticks only if the backing device was also shrunk accordingly.

For a successful shrink you have to work backwards... growing is grow partition first, then LUKS, then filesystem... shrinking is shrink filesystem first, and partition last.

---

If the resize doesn't work, it's most likely due to the backing device not being resized, for example the kernel may refuse changes to the partition table while the drive is in use. Check with blockdev that all device layers have the sizes you expect them to have.

Comment: has done a decent job of clarifying the question and giving some insight into what's going on - enough, surely, for the reward that comes from a green tick, especially in the absense of any other answers. The detailed explanation is evidence of labour and concern for the welfare of one's fellow hacks. But it is not a canonical answer to the questions posed - and that is what the reward was put up for: for the definitive statement on (i) What is "resized" if no size information is stored? and (ii) How does a "resize" get remembered across open / closes of a encrypted volume?

Comment: @markling I thought it was clear enough, but here you go.

Comment: Yeah, it's a brilliant answer. I didn't know what I was talking about. I do now, however - now that I have read it again. Ah, I see - you edited it. Well I'm certainly wiser for it now. Thank you.

Comment: can you add a bit more information ? I did the resize2fs on my partiion, my lvdisplay and pvdisplay shows the shrinked size? How can I make the volume smaller now? as far as I understand here, cryptsetup only reports a size, but does not store or have a size? so I guess next step is to go a level higher. My volume is a VirtualBox .vdi image file. is there an extra layer between VBox and Luks? I don't know. Thanks

Comment: some small precision here, --getsize64 gives a size 512 times bigger than what you want to give to cryptsetup resize --size

Comment: Interesting, but you're only seeing this result because you used an `lvresize` without the `-r` option (I do `lvextend -r`). With the `-r` (which runs `resize2fs`) both `blockdev` ops will show the expected expanded size. This can be done online, no reboot required, and no subsequent `resize2fs` required. So I'm left wondering if `cryptsetup resize` is actually completely pointless.

Comment: @EML LVM is just an example and yes, LVM can also resize the crypt for you and hopefully not mess up; but there are other cases where block devices change size (when growing RAID, when using virtual disks in a VM, etc.)