# cryptsetup resize returns device not active, despite cryptdisk status returning active and in use (resizing LVM-on-LUKS)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, luks, cryptsetup

I am in the process of resizing LVM-on-LUKS, referring to [these](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resizing_LVM-on-LUKS) [two](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=726724) posts as guides. I had done this once before smoothly, but I have run into a strange problem. When I run

```
#cryptsetup -b 377523479 resize /dev/mapper/cryptdisk

Device /dev/mapper/cryptdisk is not active.
```

However,

```
#cryptsetup status cryptdisk

 /dev/mapper/cryptdisk is active and is in use.
  type:    LUKS1
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 512 bits
  key location: dm-crypt
  device:  /dev/nvme0n1p3
  sector size:  512
  offset:  4096 sectors
  size:    438766176 sectors
  mode:    read/write
```

Any suggestions appreciated, I don't know how to proceed and have not found any information online.

Comment: by resize, do you mean grow or shrink? if it's not online resize, cryptsetup resize is optional (for LUKS1 anyway - LUKS2 has some special cases). https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/416356/30851

Comment: Oh, I guess you're shrinking. You could try adding --verbose to see what's happening. Which version of cryptsetup? Any different if you just give the name instead of full path? `dmsetup table`?

Comment: reported https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/issues/486

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround provided by @frostschutz below consists of changing the byte size to a number divisible by the offset (in this case 4096), ie

```
# cryptsetup -b 377520128 resize cryptdisk
```

This was discovered because in dmseg there was a line which stated "not aligned to h/w logical block size 4096 of (disk)". You can also note the offset in cryptsetup status.

Still, this has been registered as a bug in cryptsetup [here](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/issues/486) (again thanks to frostschutz), as a size check should happen before hand.

Hopefully this works for anyone else experiencing the problem. Note that after I ran the first command with the unmodified byte size I was still getting error messages after I changed the byte size. It wasn't until I closed and reopened the device that frostscutz's solution worked.

ie:

```
# vgchange -an
# cryptsetup luksClose cryptdisk
```

Then reopen it and restart the process with the modified byte size;

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/device cryptdisk
# vgchange -ay
# cryptsetup -b 377520128 resize cryptdisk
```

Comment: Update; after closing the device and attempting to recreate the problem, I was first given:

`# cryptsetup -b 377523479 resize cryptdisk
device-mapper: resume ioctl on cryptdisk  failed: Invalid argument`

After attempting to rerun again, I was given the original 'device not active'. 
cryptsetup status still shows the the device as active and in use.

Comment: Additional info:
# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/cryptdisk
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               <180.00 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              46079
  Free PE               106
  Allocated PE          45973
  PV UUID               O8SubL-AdqH-sKU1-Jrir-KJ9c-kHk1-Dc8ODl

Comment: # lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                UuHOj4-Hxvu-SQDZ-5Bu4-Qrp8-pPfe-bC3XRi
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2017-09-06 01:48:35 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                <171.68 GiB
  Current LE             43950
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device          253:1

Comment: --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                41lkRI-wOri-ocGc-5GOt-Ld97-fhDd-aG7rgz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2019-09-29 07:59:57 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                7.90 GiB
  Current LE             2023
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

Comment: I realized I hadn't run the following previously:
`root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# vgchange -ay
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active`
However, I still got:
`root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# cryptsetup -b 377523479 resize cryptdisk
device-mapper: resume ioctl on cryptdisk  failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: when I ran dmseg I noticed:
`device-mapper: table: 253:0: len=377523479 not aligned to h/w logical block size 4096 of nvme0n1p3`

Comment: OK, that makes a lot more sense and I can reproduce it now. Due to 4096 byte sector size, the attempt to resize fails in a way that renders the device inactive. Technically that should be considered a bug in cryptsetup. Workaround: pick an even size (multiple of 4096 bytes or 8 512-byte-sectors).

Comment: hey @frostschutz thanks for the help! I never would have thought of that, but sadly it didn't work. I tried first the next lowest multiple of 4096; `cryptsetup -b 377520128 resize cryptdisk` and got the same result (Device cryptdisk is not active) This is again after being sure it was listed as active under `cryptsetup status` and having had run `#vgchange -ay` beforehand. I also tried 8 other multiples of 512 (377524224, 377523712, 377523200, 377522688, 377522176, 377521664, 377521152, and 377520640) but all to no avail. Let me know if there is anything else I can share which might be of use

Comment: @αғsнιη please note that I am the original poster and cannot access that account. To update the issue I started this thread, please do not delete it. I have updated the original comment to include the workaround that might work for some provided by frostschutz

Comment: Hi @r1v3r please take your time and read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107 and if you believe that's your account, please ask a Moderator to merge your account into one (also I have requested a Moderator to take a look at your case). this https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/reset-password also maybe can help you

Comment: @αғsнιη I read the post and now understand that this is not a forum. Good news is that I have resolved the issue and edited the above comment to include the workaround proposed by frostshultz with some additional steps required by me for it to work on my device. Hopefully this now fits the requirement of all responses to questions including answers.

On a side note, my account user374813 doesnt have an email associated with it so I can not reset the password. This is all the more strange because with both that account and this account (r1v3r) I am certain I logged in with my google account.

Comment: good job! you can now mark your own answer as accepted meaning that, that solution resolved your question. Click a tick ✅ mark next to your answer :  )

Comment: @αғsнιη I would! ...if I could log in to user374813 :(  
But like I mentioned I before hand that account doesn't have an email associated with it so I suppose it is lost to the ether

Comment: Instead of close, reopen you can also use luksResume which can "revive" device from suspended state (but will ask for passphrase). Maybe useful if the filesystems inside LUKS were mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Both posts you linked suggest that `cryptsetup resize` takes the short name for the crypto device, not a full pathname. In other words, try this:

```
# cryptsetup -b 377523479 resize cryptdisk
```

Comment: either way works for me, but not sure if that might have changed in some version or other