# LUKS on LVM: lvresize won't work - Error: "Cannot find active LUKS dm-crypt device using..."

Tags: lvm, luks

I have a LUKs-on-LVM setup. I'm trying to `lvresize`, so I can remove a pv. However, I keep getting an error:

> Cannot find active LUKS dm-crypt device using my_vg/luks_lv.

---

More information:

My setup:

> **my_vg:** 6TB
>
> - luks_lv: 6TB (6TB ext4)
>
>   - small_pv1: 3TB
>   - small_pv2: 3TB

I added a new large drive.

> **my_vg:** 12 TB
>
> - luks_lv: 12 TB (12TB ext4)
>
>   - small_pv1: 3 TB
>   - small_pv2: 3 TB
>   - big_pv3: 6 TB

I want to move all extents from small_pv1 to the other pvs. Then remove small_pv1 from the vg. So, first I shrank the ext4 filesystem with `resize2fs`.

> **my_vg:** 12 TB
>
> - luks_lv: 12 TB (8TB ext4)
>
>   - small_pv1: 3 TB
>   - small_pv2: 3 TB
>   - big_pv3: 6 TB

I plan to expand the lv and file system to take up the entire vg after I remove the pv.

I thought I needed to resize the luks_lv LUKS partition using `cryptsetup resize`.
This didn't seem to do anything. Then I saw [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322905/what-does-cryptsetup-resize-do-if-luks-doesnt-store-partition-size), which said that was unnecessary, since I would use `cryptsetup luksClose` before doing `lvresize`.

So I tried `lvresize --size 8500G /dev/my_vg/luks_lv`. However, I got this error:

> Cannot find active LUKS dm-crypt device using my_vg/luks_lv.

`cryptsetup status /dev/my_vg/luks_lv` returns:

> /dev/my_vg/luks_lv is active.

I can still decrypt and mount luks_lv. The file system was resized as expected, but the lv still spans the entire vg.

Again, my ultimate goal is:

> **my_vg:** 9 TB
>
> - luks_lv: 9 TB (9TB ext4*)
>
>   - small_pv2: 3 TB
>   - big_pv3: 6 TB

*I know I can't get exactly 9TB because LUKS will need some space.

What is going on and how do I fix this? Thanks.

---

Edit: Adding information requested by @telcoM

`lsblk` returns:

| NAME | MAJ:MIN | RM | SIZE | RO | TYPE | MOUNTPOINTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sdc | 8:32 | 0 | 2.7T | 0 | disk |  |
| - my_vg-luks_lv | 254:1 | 0 | 10.9T | 0 | lvm |  |
| sdd | 8:48 | 0 | 5.5T | 0 | disk |  |
| - my_vg-luks_lv | 254:1 | 0 | 10.9T | 0 | lvm |  |
| sde | 8:64 | 0 | 2.7T | 0 | disk |  |
| - my_vg-luks_lv | 254:1 | 0 | 10.9T | 0 | lvm |  |

*I used whole numbers in my initial question for simplicity.

Edit 2:

I'm running Arch Linux: cryptsetup 2.6.1-3, linux 6.5.4.arch-1, lvm2 2.03.22-2.

Comment: Maybe don't use lvresize, but lvextend (which should require you to resize the crypt on the lv and then the fs on the crypt manually afterwards; also better do the first two steps with the crypt closed and the final step with the fs unmounted)

Answer (score 0):

> So I tried `lvresize --size 8500G /dev/my_vg/luks_lv`. However, I got this error:
>
> `Cannot find active LUKS dm-crypt device using my_vg/luks_lv.`

This seems implausible - LVM tools should not even look for dm-crypt devices. Was the actual command `cryptsetup resize --size 8500G /dev/my_vg/luks_lv`?

---

`cryptsetup resize` wants the name of the crypto mapping (i.e. what you are using to mount the encrypted filesystem), not of the underlying device (which is a LV in this case).

This is different from `cryptsetup status` which may be able to accept either of those.

In other words, if you are doing something like:

```
cryptsetup open /dev/my_vg/luks_lv my_crypt --type luks
mount /dev/mapper/my_crypt /where/ever
```

then `cryptsetup resize` will want something like:

```
cryptsetup resize --device-size 8300G my_crypt
lvresize --size 8500G /dev/my_vg/luks_lv
```

If you still have problems, please show the outputs of `lvdisplay -m my_vg/luks_lv` and the relevant lines of `dmsetup ls --tree -o blkdevname` or `lsblk`.

Comment: Edited OP with info you requested. The command was definitely lvresize. I tried cryptsetup resize as you suggested. That changed the size of the LUKS container. However, lvresize (while LUKS container is open) gives me a strange error: "File system size 330695704576b is adjusted for crypt data offset 16777216b. File system ext4+crypto_LUKS found on my_vg/luks_lv. File system size (8.00 TiB) is larger than the requested size (307.98 GiB). File system reduce is required (see resize2fs or --resizefs.)." I still get the same dm-crypt cannot be found error running ``lvresize`` with LUKS closed.

Comment: Your `lvresize` might be of newer version or otherwise more integrated with the dm-crypt tools (and maybe even with filesystem resizing tools?) than I have experience of. You may be using bleeding-edge software, so please add the name and version of your Linux distribution to your question post, as it might be important.

Comment: I'm running Arch Linux: cryptsetup 2.6.1-3, linux 6.5.4.arch-1, lvm2 2.03.22-2.